# HP-UX - Telnet to terminal

Tags: telnet, hp-ux

I would like to use a run of the mill linux VM to connect to an existing HP-UX server through telnet.

When I connect using the simple:

`telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

I get my login prompt and everything seems fine; however, once I am logged in, the screen display is quite garbled and I am unable to read anything reliably.

Are there telnet settings that can change terminal type or anything? There are other machines on the network using Reflections for HP, but I really only need to be able to log in for about 30 seconds each day, so an additional license seems overkill.

Also, I have found the small program called QC Term, but this is a fairly old piece of software and it does not run reliably on a Win7 machine.

Do I have any other options?

--- edit ---

Screen shot of putty connected is attached (pixelated bit is concealed purposely)

[image]

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: Oh right - this is Kingdom of Kroz. You don't want to run out of whips, and always keep a couple of teleport scrolls.

Comment: Vote to move to Arqade : http://gaming.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Once logged in set your terminal type to something like (assumming sh,ksh or bash)

```
  TERM=vt100
  export TERM
```

Comment: And if there is no command line once logged in? I'm assuming a permanent setting would need to be set on the server?

Comment: put it in your .profile on the HP/UX system

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Unfortunately that is not an option for me. I've tried also using Putty, but changing terminal type is not working.

Comment: I need to set it to HP70092, HP70096 - just not really sure how the string needs to be formed.